# In Wpf application xaml modifications are not reflecting at runtime

Tags: wpf, xaml

In Wpf application xaml modifications are not reflecting at runtime. We have some some dlls in GAC. What would be the possible reason. I am saving and re-building the applicaiton

Answer (score 0):

Do these steps :

**1. Clean the application (WPF)**

**2. Rebuild the application - Not build.**

**3. Press WindowsKey+R and Type %temp% in run window and delete all the data there**

**4. Clear your cache/cookie (Alt + Shift + del)**

Run the application. This will work. I had the same problem. The above steps solved.